# How to use extracted path params in filters in warp / rust?

Tags: rust, filter, warp

This is what I want to achieve:

I have endpoints in the form `/entity1/<id>/entity2/<id>/stuff`, i.e.:

```
let route = warp::path("entity1")
        .and(warp::path::param::<u64>())
        .and(warp::path("entity2"))
        .and(warp::path::param::<u64>())
        .and(warp::path("stuff"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(with_auth(db.clone())) // Authenticates user using Authorization header
        .and_then(handler_function);
```

I have several similar endpoints that load entity2 from the database, reject the request if it does not match to entity1, and do then stuff with the loaded entity. My idea is to create a filter that loads the entity from the database and passes it to the handler function (and does some validation, eventually rejecting the request) with something like `.and(with_entity2(db.clone()))` and

```
pub fn with_entity2(db: &Db) -> impl Filter<Extract = (Entity2,), Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone {
  // Get path params here?
}
```

I guess I could use `FullPath`, but would need to parse it myself.
Is it possible to get the path params? Or is there a better option? I wouldn't need the extracted params anymore, but I don't want to do database queries before the user is authenticated and the whole path matches.

Comment: Reading again your question I'm not sure I understand the problem. Why do you want to validate the path twice ?

Comment: I don't want to validate it twice, ideally, the path is validated (in terms of format, like ids are valid uints), then the user is authorized (jwt validation or redis), and only then data is loaded from the database requiring path parameters (and there can of course be an error leading to a rejection)

Comment: honestly I just read you already know about fullpath I really don't understand what you are doing/what. There is no reason you should have to need to parse param again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`full()`](https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/filters/path/fn.full.html) filter.

```rust
let hello = warp::path!("fullpath")
  .and(warp::filters::path::full())
  .map(|path: FullPath| format!("{}", path.as_str()));
```